# Geolocation Click Marker Event

Tags: 8, google-maps

I'm using a Geolocation Fields View with Drupal 8 and need to manipulate the Style of the Marker Info Window.
there is no class to style the pop-Up-window for the Info Text.
The Info Text has a class named gm-style-iw.
I would like to do this:

```
var popupcontent = $('.gm-style-iw');
popupcontent.parent().addClass('gmap-popup');
```

But I can't get the right event.
I can get the Click on Map Event with this:

```
   if (typeof Drupal.geolocation !== 'undefined') {
     Drupal.geolocation.googleCallbacks.push({'callback' : function () {
        Drupal.geolocation.maps[0].googleMap.addListener('click', function() {
        console.log('Clicked on the map.');
        });
     }});
    }
```

But I need to get the Click on Marker Event.
I can not figure out the Marker Objekt and the right syntax for the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (typeof Drupal.geolocation !== 'undefined') {
            Drupal.geolocation.googleCallbacks.push({'callback' : function () {
                Drupal.geolocation.maps[0].googleMap.addListener('tilesloaded', function() {
                    $('.geolocation-common-map').on('click', function() {
                        console.log('Clicked on the map.');
                    });
                });
            }});
        }
```